# Use the lm-function in R with foreach for every value in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, foreach

I have a list with the values called out which looks like this:

```
["test ~ x1", "test ~ x2" "test ~ x3" "test ~ x4"]
```

I want to use every value in this list in a lm-function. So I tried to a foreach.

```
foreach(i = 1:4) %do%
      lm(out[i], data = test_data)
```

But this does not work. Do you Guys have any idea?

Comment: The syntax showed to represent the `list` looks like a python one

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a vector and use `lapply` :

```
out <- c("test ~ x1", "test ~ x2", "test ~ x3", "test ~ x4")
result <- lapply(out, function(x) lm(x, data = test_data))
```